# Add missing date to query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been working on a Query, which returns dates based on the amount of hours worked by an employee. If there are no hours worked on a date, the date is not created for an employee either. For example:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 SUM(AantalUur) as Uren, GewerktopDatum as Datum
  FROM db gu
 JOIN Medewerkers m on m.medewerker_pk = gu.medewerker_fk
  Where m.Voornaam = 'name' 
  and COALESCE(m.Tussenvoegsel,'') LIKE 'name' 
  and m.Achternaam = 'name' 
  and GewerktOpDatum between '2017-05-16 00:00:00.0' and  '2017-05-23 00:00:00.0'
  and UrenPerWeek > 0
        GROUP BY GewerktOpDatum
```

The returned values are:

```
8       2017-05-16 00:00:00.000
8       2017-05-17 00:00:00.000
8       2017-05-18 00:00:00.000
6       2017-05-19 00:00:00.000
8       2017-05-22 00:00:00.000
6,5     2017-05-23 00:00:00.000
```

So basically,
I also want 2017-05-20, and 2017-05-21 to be returned, even though these are not in the database.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: The simplest way is probably to join to a calendar table.  If you don't have those missing dates, then you have to bring them in somehow.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen a date range function would work too and would negate management of dates (with a potential perf hit)

Comment: Sidenote: The `TOP 1000` limits your results to 1000 arbitrarily picked sums. Is this the desired behavior? Also, don't you want to specify an `ORDER BY` so the query is guaranteed to show the rows ordered by date? So far this is left to chance.

Comment: When working with several tables, you should always qualify the columns. Which table do `AantalUur`, `UrenPerWeek`, and `GewerktopDatum` reside in?

Comment: Another sidenote: Why `COALESCE(m.Tussenvoegsel,'') LIKE 'name'`? This does the same thing as a mere `m.Tussenvoegsel = 'name'`.

Comment: Thorsten, the statement gets used in a different software, where for some reason the COALESCE is needed...

Comment: Okay. Can you please answer the question which tables the columns belong to?

Comment: By the way: you are only selecting the first decisecond of 2017-05-23. That seems a bit queer. Or is `GewerktOpDatum` a mere date? Then it's strange to compare it with a date**time** range.

Answer (score 1):

As @TimBiegeleisen's suggestion, you could use a calendar table by `Recursive CTE`.

```
DECLARE @StartDate date  = dateadd(month, -3, getdate()) -- or other day that you want....
DECLARE @EndDate date = getdate()

;WITH temp AS
(
    SELECT @StartDate AS DateValue
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dateadd(day,1,t.DateValue)
    FROM temp t
    WHERE t.DateValue <= @EndDate
)
SELECT t.DateValue, ISNULL(d.Uren ,0) AS Uren
FROM temp t
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT TOP 1000 SUM(AantalUur) as Uren, GewerktopDatum as Datum
  FROM db gu
    JOIN Medewerkers m on m.medewerker_pk = gu.medewerker_fk
  Where m.Voornaam = 'name' 
     and COALESCE(m.Tussenvoegsel,'') LIKE 'name' 
     and m.Achternaam = 'name' 
     and GewerktOpDatum between '2017-05-16 00:00:00.0' and  '2017-05-23 00:00:00.0'
     and UrenPerWeek > 0
  GROUP BY GewerktOpDatum

) d ON t.DateValue = d.Datum
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to join a calander table. For example:

```
-- This will create a date range from 01-01-1900 to 01-01-2050
SELECT      DATEADD(DAY, X.RN - 1, '19000102') Dates
INTO        dbo.Calander
FROM        (
                SELECT      TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, '19000102', '20500101')) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY S1.object_id) RN
                FROM        sys.all_objects S1
                CROSS JOIN  sys.all_objects S2
            ) X

SELECT      TOP 1000 SUM(AantalUur) as Uren
,           C.Dates as Datum
FROM        db gu
JOIN        Medewerkers m 
    ON      m.medewerker_pk = gu.medewerker_fk
RIGHT JOIN  dbo.Calander C
        ON  C.Dates = m.GewerktOpDatum -- I assumed this is where GewerktOpDatum is. You should use aliases to make clear where attributes are coming from.
Where       m.Voornaam = 'name' 
        and COALESCE(m.Tussenvoegsel,'') LIKE 'name' 
        and m.Achternaam = 'name' 
        and C.Dates between '2017-05-16 00:00:00.0' and  '2017-05-23 00:00:00.0'
        and UrenPerWeek > 0
GROUP BY    C.Dates
```